# AngularJS and Rails performace issues (better integrated or separated) - js and css asset pipeline

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, amazon-ec2, asset-pipeline

I´m developing an AngularJS front-end and Rails API back-end web application. It´s time to go live so I deployed in an Amazon medium EC2 instance. I got surprised when I saw the performance (at least for main page) was not so good as expected. So, I started to investigate how could I improve the performance.

I made some performance test, and checked the results with Chrome analyze tools. I saw there was a big latency for the request I send to the server to get js or css resources.
I wrote this other post, and someone confirmed that:

[AWS EC2 micro and medium instances with same performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087597/aws-ec2-micro-and-medium-instances-with-same-performance)

I have a lot of js files because I have my app controllers separated in multiple files. And more or less for css.

I have read you can place js and css files into the assets folder in a Rails app and you can pipeline (compress all in one). This should improve the performance. My problem is that I have my AngularJS and my Rails apps completely separated (not integrated in one). So, I could deploy each one in different locations.

I thought I was so cool for developing my app this way, but now, I have big concerns about it.

Is there any solution for this? Can I move my controllers and css to assets in Rails? Or is there any similar tool for pipeline or compress files in AngularJS?

Should I integrate both AngularJS frontend and Rails backend in one single application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch of tools to achieve the same building pipeline as with rails assets pipeline
using a js environment only.

One solution is to go with grunt as a build tool and bower as package manager. 
Grunt has tons of build tasks, like preprocessing sass and coffescript and minifying and zipping css and js files.

The easiest way to setup such environment is by using [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/learning/). It has generators for different frameworks including Angular available.

You can just generate a fresh Angular project and see what it will create, than copy the Gruntfile and adapt your project structure to the generated one.